Error handling in Julia - What is the alternative to exceptions, which are "not recommended"?
The following quote is taken from the Julia documentation:

Exception handling in Julia is done using try — catch — finally, instead of try — except — finally. In contrast to Python, it is not recommended to use exception handling as part of the normal workflow in Julia (compared with Python, Julia is faster at ordinary control flow but slower at exception-catching).

This raises the question - what is the recommended way to handle error state in a Julia program?
Other ways which I am aware of

Integer return codes, such as in C
Result (or sometimes, Option) types, such as in Rust

There have been previous discussions both on this site and elsewhere which discuss in depth why (1) is a bad idea, however the quote from the Julia documentation seems to suggest that the recommended way to handle error state in a Julia program is to return arbitrary integer error codes. I find that surprising, and suspect that my interpretation is not correct.

Having spoken with some others, it has been suggested that this sentence was perhaps missing some context.
We think that what it should have said was something along the following lines:
exception handling should be avoided from within hot loops. Regions of high performance code, such as tight/hot loops should avoid raising exceptions. The reason for this is that exception handling has a small amount of overhead, but this overhead is likely to be significant compared to numerical operations on primative types which execute with very low latency
This would make sense as this advice is not specific to Julia, and would apply in languages such as C++ also. If phrased in this manner, the wording would not imply that exceptions should be avoided, only that they should be avoided in performance critical regions of code.

It depends on the sort of error. In most cases reporting exactly what has gone wrong at the point that it happens is usually more helpful than trying to lash up something by way of a fixup. Explicit defensive code where division by zero may occur or files might not open is a cleaner and faster Julia style. Although try-catch-finally isn't recommended it is available if you don't care about the performance hit.

that documentation would confuse me too. the entire section is for users coming from MATLAB, not coming from Python. Python has some general guidance that goes like "rather than figuring out first if something will succeed, just try it and catch the exception if it failed". that's good advice to give, especially to newbies (python attracts newbies), because it reinforces reliance on the exception system rather than "trying to be really really smart up front".

if that recommendation merely boils down to "exceptions are slow", the conclusion should be (1) make them faster (2) use them for exceptions, not as regular (expected branch) flow control (3) do use them in general, don't use them in numerical kernel code or other tight loops

@ChristophRackwitz unfortunately they didn't specify how slow slow is in this context... in many other languages exception handling comes with some kind of performance penalty, but that penalty is not great enough to reject using them altogether... Good point about hot numerical loops. To me it seems obvious that exceptions should not be used in tight loops but I suppose that might not be obvious to someone not coming from a Java, C++, etc background

I'd recommend that some native english speaker review the proposed paragraph. "latency" is not involved here.

@ChristophRackwitz Latency means waiting time, or delay. Hardware accelerated instructions like adding two 64 bit words have low latency.

In other words, latency is the correct word to use here. The operation of emitting, propagating and handling an exception on the other hand would be a comparatively high latency operation.

If you think of a better word, let me know

try-catch is slow, and can cause some unexpected problems since new variables in try section won't be available when it ends. I prefer to use @assert just because it's faster. And only ONE try-catch is set, at the top of business logic like web server. They're used to catch unexpected errors anyway. Context is a better option when you need to return error.

As others have commented, the alternative to the try,catch, and finally flow is not a drop-in alternative, but rather a refactoring of your code up front to handle the error's cause.
Since this is a non-specific answer, something helpful may be to benchmark the different control flows to determine whether this refactoring is worth the time investment of a refactor.
Below is a simple function written two ways: one which uses try to detect an out of bounds error, and one which uses an if to avoid the same. Note that the functions are comparable in local variable sizes, time complexity etc., and that their only real difference is choice of control flow, with the "if function" needing one extra equality check.
julia> function useTry()
    count = 0
    sizeOfVector = 50
    myVector = zeros(sizeOfVector) .+ 1 # create a vector of ones
    for i in 1:100
        try # try to add the ith element to count
            count += myVector[i]
        catch # if i is out of bounds, do nothing
            nothing
        end
    end
    return count == 50
end
useTry (generic function with 1 method)

julia> function avoidTry()
    count = 0
    sizeOfVector = 50
    myVector = zeros(sizeOfVector) .+ 1 # create a vector of ones
    for i in 1:100
        if i <= sizeOfVector # if possible, add the ith element to count
            count += myVector[i]
        else # if i is out of bounds, do nothing
            nothing
        end
    end
    return count == 50
end

avoidTry (generic function with 1 method)

julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> @btime useTry()
  308.300 μs (152 allocations: 4.88 KiB)
true

julia> @btime avoidTry()
  315.929 ns (2 allocations: 992 bytes)
true

So, using BenchmarkTools' @btime, which is essentially an improved (averages many runs) version of the built-in @time, avoidTry was 975.85x faster than useTry. Now, there are some important caveats here: runtime will vary widely based on device and current device usage,and both functions were still reasonably performant. That being said, the much larger number of allocations are an indicator that the performance difference are likely to exist similarly across devices. This allocation count (and runtime as a result) is also likely related to the amount of exceptions being handled (i.e. how many times does try error), which is another variable to consider- will the catch block be called often?
This small test, while illustrative of the issue, isn't the whole story. If you want a test similar to this, you must test runtimes with functions resembling your intended use case. Hopefully this has convinced you that the julia documentation wasn't lying about the performance difference, and to perhaps avoid try when applicable.

I don't wish to be critical unnecessarily, however I'm not sure what value this answer has for two reasons. Firstly, in the specific case of this example, you are indexing into a storage container of fixed length. Since you already know the length you can write the iteration index such that it will never be out of bounds.

Secondly, and not specific to this example, it doesn't really make sense to substitute an exception for an if statement and return some value which has no meaning. If you have an error state, and you choose to handle it with an if, and substitute a return value for something nonsensical, how can you expect users of your API to use your code in a correct way? I am somewhat generalizing beyond your specific example here.

Put another way, if your logic enters an error state, then the API should signal that to the caller somehow. Either by returning something which indicates an error in a clear and unambiguous way, or by raising an exception. eg: In this example, what would you do if the size of the vector was zero? Return -1? It isn't obvious to the caller that -1 means an error has occurred, rather than being a regular numerical return value.

All fair points- thanks for the comment. Upon re-reading the question, I agree that perhaps my answer is not on-topic. Perhaps a benchmarking of try-catch with some sort of warning  vs. the @ warn, @ info, etc. macros would have been more appropriate.

There's nothing incorrect about what you've written, you make perfectly legitimate points it's just in this context I don't think these examples capture the context

As far as I can tell the post above explains pretty well what is meant by the citation from the original post. Don't use try/catch for control flow, where if/else is more suited. In particular, there's nothing wrong with raising an exception within a hot loop (a bounds check can do that), it's raising and capturing them, especially repeatedly, that is bad.

The Julia library itself either throws an exception or uses a Nothing or Missing to return a failure state. This is similar to returning None as an Option in Rust, since the calling code would be expected to check the return for a Nothing, similar to Rust's checking for None. So perhaps returning a Nothing rather than throwing an exception is an option in keeping with the commonly used functions included with Julia, such as findfirst (see for example code at https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/6f3fdf7b36250fb95f512a2b927ad2518c07d2b5/base/strings/search.jl#L105-L119 ).

With some help from some others, we've now come to a conclusion about this which we are convinced is sensible.
It is actually the key word Python which is important here.
To repeat the quote:

In contrast to Python, it is not recommended to use exception handling as part of the normal workflow in Julia (compared with Python, Julia is faster at ordinary control flow but slower at exception-catching).

To fully appreciate what the author intended to convey here, one must first consider that in Python, there is a philosophy of ask forgiveness not permission which means to use exceptions liberally as part of the regular control flow within a program.
I don't personally always agree with this design. IMHO it depends a lot on context. Sometimes using a try-except for regular control flow is a good design. Sometimes it isn't.
That aside, in most other languages, one would not use such a design because the act of raising and handling an exception has some associated cost. Examples of such languages would be C++, Julia, probably Java although I don't have detailed knowledge of how the JVM compiles Java code.
To Summarize:
The authors point here is to discourage software engineers coming from an exclusively Python background from using exceptions just about everywhere as part of regular program control flow.
That isn't applicable to me so I somewhat misunderstood the authors intention here.
